# ElasticCloud : how to configure [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We were using ElasticSearch 6.X deployed on my own server.
We migrate recently in the cloud. So the version used is 7.X.
We have a huge query with aggregates that was working on 6.X but this query is not working anymore. 
This is due to a Breaking changes between version.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_aggregations_changes

search.max_buckets in the cluster settingedit
The dynamic cluster setting named search.max_buckets now defaults to 10,000 (instead of unlimited in the previous version). Requests that try to return more than the limit will fail with an exception.

So when, we execute the query with aggregates, we have the exception:

```
"type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
"reason" : "all shards failed",
"phase" : "query",
"grouped" : true,
"failed_shards" : [
  {
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "xxxxxxx",
    "node" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "reason" : {
      "type" : "too_many_buckets_exception",
      "reason" : "Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level setting.",
      "max_buckets" : 10000
    }
  }
```

We don't have time to change query so how can we configure the parameter on ElasticCloud?
Or can I add a parameter to the query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on the ElasticSearch website:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/increasing-max-buckets-for-specific-visualizations/187390